nslookup error when I use scrapy, I can access the site with a browser
import scrapy

class CninfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cninfo_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.cninfo.com.cn/new/commonUrl/pageOfSearch?url=disclosure/list/search']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract the table rows
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@id="notice-table"]/tbody/tr')

        for row in rows:
            # Extract the data from each column
            code = row.xpath('.//td[1]/span[@class="code"]/text()').get()
            name = row.xpath('.//td[2]/span[@class="code"]/text()').get()
            announcement_title = row.xpath('.//td[3]/a/text()').get()
            announcement_time = row.xpath('.//td[4]/span[@class="date"]/text()').get()

            yield {
                'code': code.strip() if code else None,
                'name': name.strip() if name else None,
                'announcement_title': announcement_title.strip() if announcement_title else None,
                'announcement_time': announcement_time.strip() if announcement_time else None,
            }


C:\Users\Steven\cninfo_scraper>scrapy crawl cninfo_spider
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.11.1 started (bot: cninfo_scraper)
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.3.0, libxml2 2.10.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.9.0, w3lib 2.1.2, Twisted 24.3.0, Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 24.1.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023), cryptography 41.0.5, Platform Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.addons] INFO: Enabled addons:
[]
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 4e5a2f9878fdbea5
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'cninfo_scraper',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'cninfo_scraper.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['cninfo_scraper.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt>: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1999, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = context.run(
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 519, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.value.with_traceback(self.tb))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 54, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1078, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 1025, in startConnectionAttempts
    raise error.DNSLookupError(
twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn> (failed 1 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://cninfo.com.cn>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1999, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = context.run(
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 519, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.value.with_traceback(self.tb))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 54, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1078, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 1025, in startConnectionAttempts
    raise error.DNSLookupError(
twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1314,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.4481,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3, 2, 47, 33, 867424, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/ERROR': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'retry/count': 4,
 'retry/max_reached': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 4,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError'>": 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3, 2, 47, 33, 419324, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2024-04-03 10:47:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

C:\Users\Steven\cninfo_scraper>scrapy crawl cninfo_spider
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.11.1 started (bot: cninfo_scraper)
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.3.0, libxml2 2.10.3, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.9.0, w3lib 2.1.2, Twisted 24.3.0, Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 24.1.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023), cryptography 41.0.5, Platform Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.addons] INFO: Enabled addons:
[]
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 67028393706b5607
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'cninfo_scraper',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'cninfo_scraper.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['cninfo_scraper.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2024-04-03 10:52:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://cninfo.com.cn/robots.txt>: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1999, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = context.run(
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 519, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.value.with_traceback(self.tb))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 54, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1078, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 1025, in startConnectionAttempts
    raise error.DNSLookupError(
twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn> (failed 1 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://cninfo.com.cn> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://cninfo.com.cn>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1999, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = context.run(
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 519, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.value.with_traceback(self.tb))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 54, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1078, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 1025, in startConnectionAttempts
    raise error.DNSLookupError(
twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: cninfo.com.cn.
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 6,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1314,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.460191,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3, 2, 52, 9, 246305, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/ERROR': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'retry/count': 4,
 'retry/max_reached': 2,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 4,
 "robotstxt/exception_count/<class 'twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError'>": 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 3, 2, 52, 8, 786114, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2024-04-03 10:52:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

I can access cninfo with a browser.

Can you just try using the known ip instead of the domain name?

start_urls = [ 'http://124.217.130.49/new/commonUrl/pageOfSearch?url=disclosure/list/search']         That doesn't work.

Cannot access cninfo.com.cn using the browser. host cninfo.com.cn shows only MX host, ping brings an error  ping: cninfo.com.cn: No address associated with hostname. How did get IP address 124.217.130.49? www.ninfo.com.cn has IP addresses 199.91.74.{178, 176, 214, 219}.

@YuriGinsburg, I've been able to ping it from my side and got a different IP: 156.59.207.13. Seems a bit jumpy, that one

Works for me: Retrying <GET https://www.cninfo.com.cn/new/commonUrl/pageOfSearch?url=disclosure/list/search> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', '', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]>]
